# Qual a forma correta de montar interfaces em páginas PHP?

Tags: php, javascript

Em vários projetos que vi por ai, em que são necessárias consultas a bancos de dados para conseguir informação, e posteriormente montar tabelas, notei a seguinte abordagem apresentada no trecho de código abaixo:

```
<?php
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)) {
?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $row['nome']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['idade']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['dia']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['turno']; ?></td>
    </tr>
<?php
    }
?>
```

Nela, a pessoa abre diversas vezes `<?php ?>` para extrair informações do banco, e montar a página.

Isso não me parece correto, não seria melhor usar javascript(ajax) para recuperar informação, e depois DOM para montar a página?

Minha dúvida é qual seria a melhor maneira de construir páginas em que é necessário fazer consultas a bancos de dados para obter informação.

Comment: A tua pergunta, apesar de interessante, é baseada em opiniões. Por exemplo, como sou desenvolvedor PHP eu defenderia o PHP, o mesmo com JS, AJAX e tal. Não existe resposta certa, somente opiniões.

Comment: Não da pra considerar errado, com ajax é mais bonito, fluido e rápido, mas com um loop do php é mais simples de se executar.

Comment: @ThiagoSantos Não seria considerado uma má prática utilizar o PHP dessa forma?

Comment: Não é nem questão de gosto, é dependente do alvo do projeto. 
Montar os dados por JavaScript traz complicações para SEO. Se o projeto necessita de compatibilidade para SEO, é uma roubada montar o conteúdo pelo JavaScript / DOM. Não tem uma forma "mais correta". Tem aquilo que é mais adequado para o projeto com o qual se trabalha.

Comment: @DanielCosta Realmente, utilizando Ajax seria um pouco mais complicado, só quero confirmar se fazer dessa forma com PHP não é considerado uma má prática.

Comment: Me parece que na verdade o grande problema da pergunta é que ela é ampla ou talvez não clara, e por isso indica ser ampla. Abrir o PHP várias vezes não é um grande problema, é assim que é feito mesmo. Tem como fazer diferente, mas muda muito pouco. Usar AJAX pode ser mais interessante mesmo, em muitos casos, mas não em todos. Mas se não souber como fazer direito pode ser pior. Não parece que tenha um problema específico que queira resolver aqui.

Comment: @GaMen e por que o código apresentado seria má prática? Não tem nada errado. Exceto quanto ao uso da função mysql_* : http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/579

Comment: @DanielOmine Sim, a função mysql_* foi só pra ilustrar, imagina que eu usei PDO no exemplo. Eu não sou muito experiente com PHP, e isso de abrir várias vezes <?php ?> me pareceu errado, por isso a pergunta.

Comment: @bigown Não sou muito experiente com PHP, eu só queria saber mesmo se isso era errado e se não tinha uma maneira melhor de resolver o problema.

Comment: Não tem nada errado em abrir e fechar as tags. Isso até facilita para evitar misturar com HTML. No exemplo da pergunta está muito simples, mas se vc coloca outros elementos como imagens, textos, javascript, css, aí fica complicado pois precisa escapar caracteres especiais. Fica um código mais "sujinho".

Comment: @DanielOmine Sim, achei que o código fica meio bagunçado fazendo dessa forma. Principalmente na parte em que a chave do `while` é aberta numa tag `<?php ?>` e depois fechada em outra. Mas já que não é errado fazer isso, vou utilizar menos DOM nos meu códigos. Muito obrigado!

Comment: o que eu disse é que fica mais organizado mesmo com muitos elementos.  E que de outra forma é que fica bagunçado..

Comment: @GaMem tenha em mente que mesmo com PHP existe várias formas de se trabalhar. Se você preza por um código organizado pode tranquilamente adotar um template engine e aplicar MVC. Dá para carregar previamente todos os dados antes de montar a página HTML. Tudo depende do que você quer, PHP é conhecido pela sua extrema flexibilidade.

Comment: @AdrianoLuz Vou pesquisar mais sobre isso, obrigado. Fiz essa pergunta, por que fazer coisas como `<a href="<?php echo 'caminho'; ?>">Link</a>` me pareciam bem erradas.

Comment: @DanielOmine Ah sim, te entendi mal. Mas não acho muito agradável de se ver de qualquer forma. Muito obrigado por se dispor a ajudar.

Comment: @GaMen em vez de utilizar `<?php echo $row['nome']; ?>` pode utilizar `<?= $row['nome']; ?>`

Comment: Não tem nada de errado, mas muita gente chama a esse método de código esparguete, apesar do código ser fácil de compreender e de criar no inicio, a logo prazo é uma dor de cabeça de manter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não tem nada de errado em abrir e fechar as tags para compor o conteúdo do HTML.

Tudo que está delimitado pela tag do PHP é parseado pelo compilador do PHP.

Se você passa coisas não referentes ao PHP, isso tem um custo a mais para o compilador processar os dados.

Vejamos um exemplo:

```
echo '<table><tr><td>'.$variavel.'</td></tr></table>';
```

Aqui nesse exemplo, o PHP vai apenas "cuspir" de volta o trecho estático `<table><tr><td>` e `</td></tr></table>`.

Ou seja, enviou para o compilador processar um texto que não tem o que ser processado. É uma informação estática. O PHP teve que ler essa informação, aumentando o consumo de memória e processamento.

De outro modo,

```
<table><tr><td><?php echo $variavel;?></td></tr></table>
```

O compilador vai receber apenas o trecho `$variavel;`.

O que seria uma prática ruim, é algo assim

```
<?php
echo $variavel;
?>
<?php
echo $outra_variavel;

function alguma_coisa() {
    return null;
}

echo alguma_coisa();
?>
```

Aqui nesse caso sim, temos até um problema pois fechou e abriu desnecessariamente pois o código seguinte é também PHP. Poderia apenas continuar na mesma tag

```
<?php
echo $variavel;

echo $outra_variavel;

function alguma_coisa() {
    return null;
}

echo alguma_coisa();
?>
```

Além disso, ao fazer

```
?>
<?php
```

Está gerando um output que normalmente é a causa comum entre novatos com o famoso "header already sent". Mas não vou entrar nesse assunto pois é mais extenso e desvia do foco da questão.

## Escapando aspas

Uma dificuldade quando passa tudo pelo PHP é ter que escapar caracteres:

```
echo '<tr><td>texto com aspa simples \''.$variavel.'</td></tr>';
```

Pode-se resolver usando aspa dupla

```
echo "<tr><td>texto com aspa simples '".$variavel."</td></tr>";
```

Mas isso depende muito também do padrão de código do projeto. Particularmente utilizo aspa simples e há quem prefira aspa dupla. Isso é questão de opinião e um tanto polêmico. No entanto, mesmo com aspa dupla cai na mesma cilada quando o texto estático possui aspa dupla. É preciso fazer o escape:

```
echo "<tr><td>texto com aspa dupla \"".$variavel."</td></tr>";
```

Até aqui são exemplos muito simples. Na vida real você vai ter coisas assim

```
lorem ipsum single quot'e double "quote"
<b>
<script>
var str = "foo'bar";
document.write(str);
</script>
<?php echo $variavel_do_php;?>
</b>
```

Isso aqui ainda é um nível bem criança... mas é apenas para ilustrar

Veja como fica de outra forma:

```
echo '
lorem ipsum single quot\'e double "quote"
<b>
<script>
var str = "foo\'bar";
document.write(str);
</script>
'.$variavel_do_php.'
</b>';
```

Diz aí qual dos dois é melhor para leitura de código?

Em termos de performance não fazem diferença. Por isso eu normalmente opto pelo que é mais simples e legível e, lógico, tudo depende da finalidade de uso e isso é o que mais importa.

## JavaScript Template

Quanto ao uso de JavaScript para montar a view, deve-se avaliar os requisitos do projeto. Se é um projeto web, normalmente um website tem que ser compatível com SEO. Se montar as páginas via JavaScript terá problemas com SEO pois os mecanismos de busca não interpretam o JavaScript.

O esquema de montagem do layout com JavaScript foi muito usado no passado antes da "Era Google". Era muito comum os sites montarem o conteúdo das páginas com JavaScript pois reduz bastante o código HTML. Infelizmente todos foram forçados a aumentar conteúdo redundante nas páginas devido ao SEO.

Atualmente é usado mais para projetos privados, intranets ou mesmo websites que não se importam com SEO.

## MVC

Se analisar o código da pergunta para um projeto em MVC, podemos sim dizer que não é uma boa prática pois no MVC normalmente não invoca funções do PHP diretamente na View. É normalmente usando um template engine, helpers, etc.

## Resumindo

Destaquei apenas pontos óbvios. E ainda há muitos outros pontos para mencionar mas isso torna o assunto extenso demais.

No geral, evite pensar em "o que é o melhor para X ou Y?". Enxergue essa pergunta como "o que é mais adequado para o projeto X ou situação Y?". Pois não existe algo que seja "a solução universal". Existem soluções diversas que se adequam melhor para uma determinada situação.

## Minimizando a sujeira visual

Para quem se incomoda com o uso de `<?php echo $variavel;?>`, é possível reduzir usando short tag.

O equivalente a isso `<?php echo $variavel;?>` pode ser escrito como `<?=$variavel;?>`

Lembrando que houve uma época em que cogitou-se a eliminação da short tag. Nessa época, por precaução, eu parei de usar. Um tempo depois voltaram atrás e decidiram manter mas mesmo assim continuo evitando o uso por precaução. Mas isso é escolha pessoal. Não quero dizer que deve pensar igual.

O uso de `<?php` é recomendado para evitar confusão com documentos XML que também usam `<?` como tag.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<note>
  <to>Tove</to>
  ....
```